# Linux: what does minus asterisk -* mean in bash script

Tags: linux

Linux: what does minus asterisk -* mean in a bash script in the end of line:

```
tar -czvf  $pfad/toolkitdb.log.`date -d "yesterday" +%Y-%m-%d`.tar.gz toolkitdb.log.`date -d "yesterday" +%Y-%m-%d`*
rm $pfad/toolkitdb.log.`date -d "yesterday" +%Y-%m-%d`-*
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means it will remove all the files ending with yesterday's date, a `-` and then any character, like

```
$pfad/toolkitdb.log.2017-07-09-14/
$pfad/toolkitdb.log.2017-07-09-test/
```

You have to replace `$pfad` with the correct value.

For instance, you could try the command:

```
ls $pfad/toolkitdb.log.`date -d "yesterday" +%Y-%m-%d`-*
```

to see the output files.

Answer (score 0):

dash (-) has no special meaning there. start (*) will match any characters any number of times, so its just a wild card for "match anything after -" in this case they expect numbers

Answer (score 0):

Insert-Completions (M-*)
Insert all completions of the text before point that would have been generated by possible-completions.


Source: https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#index-insert_002dcompletions-_0028M_002d_002a_0029